# Take Screenshot on left mouse click electron

Tags: electron

I am making an app of myself to collect evidence i have made an app that takes screenshots after clicking and button on the app but I want to call a function that is called when a user clicks anywhere on the screen even when the app is minimised.

npm packages i am using are screenshot-desktop

```
const screeno = require('screenshot-desktop')
const os = require ('os');
const username = os.userInfo ().username;
async function takeScreenshot() {
  var filename="/Users/"+username+"/OneDrive/Desktop/FI/"+Date.now()+".jpg";
  screeno({ filename: filename })
}

function handleKeyPress (event) {
  // You can put code here to handle the keypress.
  console.log(`You pressed ${event.button}`)
}


document.getElementById('screenshot-button').addEventListener('click', takeScreenshot);
```

Comment: i dont think electron have such a built in function neither nodejs. you have to use third part packages like `global-mouse-events` which use os api to implement this